# MSSQL: Why is this index 10 times faster than the other one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, nhibernate, database-design

i found a very strange behaviour for which i have to explanation. We have a simple table with around 450.000 entries (MSSQL 2008 R2).

The indexes for this table are very simple:

Index #1 contains:

```
[OwnerUserID] -> int, 4 byte
[TargetQuestionID] -> int, 4 byte
[LastChange] -> date,  8 byte
```

Index #2 contains:

```
[LastChange] is a date, 8 byte
[OwnerUserID] is an int, 4 byte
[TargetQuestionID] is an int, 4 byte
```

As you can see, the difference is only in the slightly different order of the columns; in both indexes, the leafs have the same size, 16 bytes (far away from what i've seen doing some DBAs on really big databases)

The queries are simple:

```
Query #1:
- Asks just for the last entried element ( top(1) ) ordered by LastChange, so it takes only LastChange into account

Query #2:
- Asks just for the last entried element ( top(1) ) entried for a distinct OwnerUserID, so it takes OwnerUserID and LastChange into account
```

Results are:

Index #1 is super slow for query #1, albeit i thought it should be OK since the data leafs are really not big (16 bytes)

Index #2 is super slow for query #2 (but since it takes two values into account, OwnerUserID + LastChange = 8 bytes, i do not see any reason why it should be much slower/faster)

Our idea was to have only one index, but since the performance for each query scenario differs by 10 - 11 times, we ended up creating just BOTH of these indexes in parallel, where we thought we could go with one - since the index is not that big/complex that you would actually think this slight difference in column-order would hurt.

So, now we are wasting doubled space and since the table grows around by 10k rows per day, we will have diskspace issues somewhere in the future...

First, i thought this is because of some internal NHibernate issues, but we checked in Performance Monitor and the results are absolutely reproduceable.

It seems like MSSQL performance with indexes depends highly on the usage of datetime-columns, since this simple example shows that this could crash the whole performance :-/

Comment: Check the execution plans.

Comment: Hehe, thats true - we checked only SQL profiler to see how long it takes, but not the execution plan :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly indices are used to make a fast binary search possible, instead of slow sequential search. To achieve this they store the index keys in sorted order or in a tree. But a binary search is only possible, if the start of the key is known, and thus the order of the elements is important. In your case this means:

- Query#1 needs the record with the lowest LastChange. This query can be optimized with an index, which starts with LastChange, e.g. Index#2. With Index#1 it needs to fall back to a sequential search.
- Query#2 needs first to find all unique OwnerIds and an index which starts with the OwnerId can help here. Then it needs to find the lowest LastChange for a specific OwnerId. Index#1 does not help here anymore, because the next field in the index is not LastChange. Index#2 might help here if there are lots of records for the same OwnerId. Otherwise it will probably do an sequential search.

So for an index the order of fields should match the queries. Also you might need to update your statistics so that the query planner has an idea if it is better to do a sequential search (few entries per OwnerId) or use Index#2 too (lots of entries per OwnerId). I don't know if and how this can be done with mysql, only know it from postgresql.

Index is always a trade-off: it slows down inserts, but speeds up queries. So it highly depends on your application how many indices you have and how they will be constructed.

Comment: Adding to that: Use the tools you have instead asking a question. Look at the query plans - they will gladly show you which indices are used. Management Studi can nicely fvisualize them.

Comment: TomTom, as said above: Great idea -  execution plans we didn't check, only SQL Profiler...